# React Router 1.0 using router.transitionTo() without Navigation mixin

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, react-router

Is there an easier way to access the `Router` object from a component to do things like call `transitionTo()` without using the Navigation mixin? This is an ES6 component. Currently on an event like a button click, I have been writing something like this:

```js
class Button extends React.Component {
  handleClick(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var router = this._reactInternalInstance._context.router;
    router.transitionTo('/search');
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <button onClick={this.handleClick.bind(this)}>
        {this.props.children}
      </button>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Confused, why not just `this.context.router`?

Comment: Contexts in ES6 is undocumented at the moment. You accept the context in a parameter of the constructor and pass the context to the super. You can then access the context normally. Code examples in [this react-router issue](https://github.com/rackt/react-router/issues/1059).

Comment: Thanks @MatGessel!! I'll document the solution below.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Per [Mat Gessel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/199296/mat-gessel)'s comment, adding the context as a parameter in the constructor will give you access to the router.

```js
class Button extends React.Component {
  constructor(props, context) {
    super(props, context);
    this.context = context;      
  }

  handleClick(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.context.router.transitionTo('/search');
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <button onClick={this.handleClick.bind(this)}>
        {this.props.children}
      </button>
    );
  }
}

Button.contextTypes = {
  router: React.PropTypes.object.isRequired
};
```